# mysql java: insert a row with some parametres don't work

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I try to execute this request

```
window.requete ="INSERT INTO logfile VALUES(" + omsg.get_Creator() +","+ omsg.get_CreatorParent() +","+ omsg.get_SequenceNumber()+ ","+omsg.get_CreatorCost()+ ","+omsg.get_CreatorEnergy()+","+interval+","+lplinterval+ ","+omsg.get_Data()+"," + tmp2+")";

try { Statement stmt = window.connexion.createStatement();
    int resultat = stmt.executeUpdate(requete);
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    window.error("pb insert"); 
}
```

I get an exception while inserting. Is there something wrong in my syntax?

My table contains:

```
| Creator(INT) | CreatorParent(INT) | SequenceNumber(INT) | CreatorCost(INT) | CreatorEnergy |
| Data(INT) | SampInterval(INT) | LplInterval(INT) | SampTime (DATETIME)|
```

Comment: Always: What is the errormessage? But it seems the last tmp2-thing you insert is not in the table.

Comment: And the usual comment: don't EVER insert values in a SQL-statement by string-concatenation. ALWAYS use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Stringbased values needs to be quoted in SQL string. But, better is to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Then you don't worry about quoting the values nor about escaping from [SQL injection attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO logfile VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, logMessage.getCreator());
preparedStatement.setInt(2, logMessage.getCreatorParent());
preparedStatement.setInt(3, logMessage.getSequenceNumber());
preparedStatement.setInt(4, logMessage.getCreatorCost());
preparedStatement.setInt(5, logMessage.getCreatorEnergy());
preparedStatement.setInt(6, interval);
preparedStatement.setInt(7, lplinterval);
preparedStatement.setInt(8, logMessage.getData());
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(9, new Timestamp(tmp2.getTime())); // Assuming tmp2 is java.util.Date.
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

*(and work on your [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), yours is pretty terrible, also don't forget to properly close JDBC resources, you don't seem to take this into account as well)*

---

**Update**: as per the comments, `tmp2` is a `String`. Here's how you could convert it to `Date` so that you can use it in `setTimestamp()` so that the value will be properly saved in a `DATETIME` column type. Since you didn't mention what date format the `tmp2` is in, I'll just take `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` as an example:

```
String datestring = "2011-05-19 12:34:56"; // Just an example. 
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(datestring);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
// Store in SQL string by PreparedStatement#setTimestamp().
```

Comment: Hi, THX, mp2 is a string and the comumn 9 is DateTime and not timestamp.  why do u add new timestamp?

Comment: JDBC `Timestamp` is the right type for MySQL `DATETIME` type. See also http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html. You just need to convert `String` to `Date` by `SimpleDateFormat` and then wrap it in `new Timestamp()`.

Comment: i'v always the pb !! the conversion work well but the query throw exception !_!

Comment: Well, just read the exception message and stacktrace and fix the code accordingly. More can't I be of help to you since you didn't share the exception details. Exceptions contain very important information about the cause of the problem. By doing as if they are for decoration and thus ignoring them you don't help yourself much in fixing the problem ;)

Comment: may be it because i'v some fiels smallint(4) ? whad do u think?

Comment: Hard to tell without any information about the exception. Further, I am not really motivated to communicate back to someone who communicates in a childish way with "I'v", "fiels", "whad", "u", etc. Please pay a bit more attention to your English. This is not a text/SMS/chat box at disney.com or something :)

Comment: Thank you all!! for your help , i resolved the problems. and sorry for my bad english! i'm not a native speacker!have a great day !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need quotes around your datetime field.  ,'" + tmp2+"')"

Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)